# How do collinear/non-collinear vectors change expressions?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

$\overrightarrow u and \overrightarrow  v are$ non-collinear vectors, $\overrightarrow w$ is a non-zero vector.
$$\overrightarrow w = m\overrightarrow u+n\overrightarrow v$$

We can express $\overrightarrow u$as:
$$\overrightarrow u =\frac{1}{m}\overrightarrow w-\frac{n}{m}\overrightarrow v$$
This is true for $\overrightarrow u$ as long as $\overrightarrow  w$ and $\overrightarrow v$ are not collinear.

What happens when the vectors are collinear?

Comment: In this case, $m=0$, so you can't divide by it.

Comment: Why is $m = 0$?

Comment: Because w is just a multiple of v.

Comment: If it was $\overrightarrow w = \overrightarrow u+n\overrightarrow v$ would w and v be able to be collinear?

Comment: No, not if u and v are not collinear.